# Configure SWR fetcher and axios global in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, swr

Here is my fetcher and my application is becoming too bulky that i wouldn't want to be calling it in evvery component, how do i configure the fetcher to be accessible everywhere in my application.

```
     const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((resp) => resp);
```

I also want to set a default baseURL for axios in my application so i wouldn't have to be using the full url everytime i'm trynna make a request, so i did

```
    axios.defaults.baseURL= "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"
```

in my App.js, but it doesn't work.

Is there a better way to achieve these two problems using SWR?

Comment: `.then((resp) => resp);` ... what is the purpose of this null code

Comment: this is a promise that resolves the data and also throws an error if there is any

Comment: For SWR global configuration see https://swr.vercel.app/docs/global-configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by creating new axios instance with whole config and then import it anywhere you want to make a call instead of importing axios package.

e.g.

in api.js

```
import { axios } from 'axios';

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

in any other file when you want to use it

```
import { axiosInstance } from 'path/api'

axiosInstance.get('/pathAfterBaseUrl')
```

Comment: I did create new Axios instance and and my fetcher as well in a config file then I was able to import it and use it anywhere within my application, thanks that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

In Api.js

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://your-api.com/v1',
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  },
});
export default instance;
```

Then use it in swr's fetcher function

```
import instance from './Api.js';

const fetcher = async (key, params) => {
  const resp = await instance.get(`/route?id=${key}&param=${params}`).then(res => res.data);
  return resp;
};
const { data, error } = useSWR([key, params], fetcher);
```